# Send button returning error codes, like button works fine

Tags: facebook, send

I have a like/send button that I've set up on a customer's home page.  I have it pointed at their facebook profile page so that when people like them either from facebook or on their homepage, it's always liking the same thing.

Anyway, I've used the fb social plugins page to create the fbxml, and I'm having a problem with the send button.  The like button works wonderfully, but the send button doesn't want to cooperate.

First, I had the button set up using "http://www.facebook.com/AFEDEWA" as the link to like/send.  However, with the button(s) configured that way, when you click on Send you get an error message that says "The page at ttp://www.facebook.com/AFEDEWA could not be reached because the server returned status code 200."

So I did some digging on the 'net, and found some info that seemed to indicate that maybe the send button didn't like the alias / page name.  I tried putting in the page id instead, and when I do that I get a different error: "The page at ttp://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=165721903513327 could not be reached."

(I removed the h in the front of the links in those messages because the board was complaining about too many links.  But the actual error message has the http in full :) )

The link works either way if you c/p into your browser, and also works fine with the like button.  It would appear that the send button has some issues?  Maybe needs to handle redirects instead of returning a 200 OK message.... ?

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.  If you want to see the like/send button in action, this is the website it's set up on: http://www.coolersecurityadvisors.com

thx!

Comment: 'ttp://www.facebook.com/AFEDEWA' you'll find the error yourself ;-) The button works without errors for me btw.

Comment: I'm confused by your comment... are you referring to the fact that I left the "h" off the front of "http"?  If so, that's just something that I did when I posted this message because the board was complaining about too many links.

Also, you say the button works fine for you -- are you referring to the like or the send button that works fine?

thanx!!

Comment: Yes, I was referring to the missing 'h' in 'http'. I tried the Send and Like button. When I clicked on the Send button it showed me the preview image a title and description of the URL I was about to send. And the Like Button just worked. Showed no error.

Comment: Yeah, the like button is working fine.  Which send button did you click?  The one in the sidebar (under "social"), or the one @ the bottom of the blog post?  The blog post send is working fine, it's the one in the sidebar that I'm having problems with.  Is that one working for you as well, because I still see the error...  thanx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After checking the buttons on the upper right, I found an issue. It seems like you can not Like/Send URL's of real Facebook Pages using the Like/Send button. Facebooks URL debugger always comes up with the error "Facebook can not crawl itself".

If you just want that people share a link to your Facebook Page, simply create a file on your server, implement the OpenGraph Tags you want to show up on Facebook (title, image, etc.) and output this in case the Facebook crawler is visiting this site, if it's not the Facebook crawler, redirect the user to https://www.facebook.com/AFEDEWA

Comment: Thank you for looking into this for me, Bjorn.  I will look into implementing your workaround and/or just removing the send button from that location since it's not supported in the way that I'm using it.  thx!

Comment: The solution I ended using was to set "send=false" on the like button, and then adding in a <fb:send button after it with the home page URL.  Now the likes keeps consistent count w/the fb page count, and the send button works to send the website to others :)  Thanx again for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

Fix up the 8 warnings from https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.coolersecurityadvisors.com%2F and I think that might help solve the problem.

Comment: Hmm, can you help me understand what that page is telling me?  I'm wondering because they seem to mention "rendering a news feed story" and that's not what my like/send button is doing.  However, there is also a facebook wall feed on that page (which is working fine), so I'm not sure if that is what it's referring to in that page.
thanx!

Comment: Isn't the href for his like/send button pointing to his facebook page? Therefore there is no need to fix those errors as FB isn't trying to lint his homepage.

Comment: @nav;  thanx for clearing that up!  That was what I was thinking looking @ that page as well.