# How to send a Facebook page as url using the Facebook send button?

Tags: facebook, button, facebook-opengraph, send, facebook-page

I will try to explain a bit the context for my problem.

**Context:**

A while ago I started working on Facebook application. One of the requirements is to be included in a Facebook page as a tab. This application will contain on a page a send button in order to be able to make it more engaging with specific people, users of the application would choose on their own. The reason behind this is because the Facebook page containing the application is related to alcohol, and "liking" the application will get more audition and potential children. Another reason for using send button rather then other similar options from Facebook (like send dialog etc.) is because in Facebook documentation was stated that send button works on mobile devices and other options don't.

**Problem:**

My problem is related to the send button. What I need is to be able to completely configure the send button: url, image, title, description. I have research the open graph tags in order to be able to do this. Everything works fine if the page I want to be sent with the message is a website OUTSIDE Facebook. Once I started to use the url of a Facebook page (let's call it www.facebook.com/mycustompage), then the crawler takes the images, title, description from facebook.com ignoring the actual page and the produced message is not what I want.

I have searched a lot to better understand this limitation and could not find anything relevant.
The only article I could find as a potential solution was (and even this I had trouble finding):
[Send button returning error codes, like button works fine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8714890/send-button-returning-error-codes-like-button-works-fine)

The above discussion is a workaround which I have already put in place but is not 100% what I want. The described workaround is about putting in the send button:

```
    <div class="fb-send" data-href="http://www.mycustomdomain.com/og"></div>
```

a page that sniffs the user agent. In case the user agent is Facebook crawler to serve an html empty page just with the open graph tags, otherwise redirect to the desired URL - which in our case is the facebook page www.facebook.com/mycustompage.

The message produced contains:

- the title which is a link to www.mycustomdomain.com/og which when
  clicked opens a page in a new tab with the address
  www.facebook.com/mycustompage - this is relatively ok
- under the title I have a "sub-title" readonly text containing the domain of the link: www.mycustomdomain.com  - THIS IS NOT OK since I don't want to share where I have hosted the application.
- the image and the desired description - this is ok.

**Conclusion:**

1. What I want to know if there is a better way to do this rather than this workaround.
2. If not I would like to know how I can hide for the produced message the "sub-title" so that the hosted domain is not visible.

Comment: Use the Send dialog instead – it allows you to set most of the link’s properties yourself. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/

Comment: Thanks, but I have already read the article you posted. In the beginning of my question I have explained why I have remained hooked on send button rather than other options like send dialog - i need something that works also on mobile. In the article you mentions it is stated and I quote "This Dialog is currently not supported on mobile devices."